Solving the following differential equation seems to be very cumbersome.
I don't even know how to begin. I tried conventional methods such as change of parameters and Laplace but the calculations became heavily cumbersome. there should be a better way to solve this. The question specify's that it needs a particular solution.
$$
\begin{align*}
&+ \left(3\cos^2(x) + 2\cos(x) + 4\right)y + 3y' + \left(7\cot^2(x) + 2\cot(x) + 9\right)y'' \\
&= 7 \left(6e^{2x} + 9e^x + 7\right)\left(3\cos^2(x) + 2\cos(x) + 4\right) \\
&\quad + (2e^x + 1) \cdot 3 \left(3\cos^2(x) + 2\cos(x) + 4\right) \\
&\quad + 3 \cdot 7 \left(e^x \cdot 1 \cdot 6 \cdot 2 e^x + e^x \cdot 1 \cdot 9 \cdot 1\right) \\
&\quad + 3 \left(e^x \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 1\right) \cdot 3 \\
&\quad + \left(7\cot^2(x) + 2\cot(x) + 9\right)\left(7 \left(e^x \cdot 1 \cdot e^x \cdot 1 \cdot 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 1\right)\right) \\
\end{align*}
$$
with $y(0)=163$ and $y'(0)= 153$.
EDIT : The answer sheet provides the following for the answer :
$$
42e^{2x} + 69e^x + 52.
$$
I don't know if it is truly the right answer to this. but how can one arrive at this?

more context can help

@SineoftheTime this was a question in one of my overall practice problems. it isn't associated with any particular chapter.

@Moo yes. I don't know.

@SDFXH The first step would be to simplify. Can you do that?

@Vasili other than multiplying numbers and basic trig identities no.

@Moo yes i am sure

It seems unlikely the homogenous equation has any sort of closed form solution.

@eyeballfrom i have been informed that the whole equation has a closed form solution by my teacher.

(Again) Please simplify. For instance $e^x \cdot 1 \cdot e^x \cdot 1 \cdot 6 \cdot 2 \cdot 1=12e^{2x}$. And $A(3c^2+2c+4)+B(3c^2+2c+4)=(A+B)(3c^2+2c+4)$.
